# Copy files from android/data directory to internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-file

I have 2 files which are located deep in the android/data system, example of such a file below.

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mytest.com.test/files/Documents/Test/Bin/data.dat
```

I want to copy both of them to a location on the internal storage.
Now stackoverflow is a nice community which has a lot of examples and I therefore searched already for some examples how it is done but unfortunatly it is not working.

Logcat:

```
V/debug: Copy file failed. Source file missing.
```

I verified this but the files are definitely there, the destination directory is created but is **empty**.
Could anybody please assist me?

Main backup method:

```
public void backupFavorites() {

        String folder1, folder2, folder3, folder4;

        //Set target directory
        String path = Utils.getDownloadDestination(this) + "/FavoritesBackup/Bin/";
        File rootPath = new File(path);

        if (!rootPath.exists())
            rootPath.mkdirs();

        //Prepare Sourcefile 1
        folder1 = (rootPath + "/" + "data.dat");
        File sdcardData = new File (this.getExternalFilesDir
                ("Documents"), "MyTestApp");
        String pathdata = sdcardData.getPath() + "/Bin/data.dat";
        File data = new File(pathdata);

        //Prepare Sourcefile 2
        folder2 = (rootPath + "/" + "trackerdata.dat");
        File sdcardTracker = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir
                ("Documents"), "MyTestApp");
        String pathtracker = sdcardTracker.getPath() + "/Bin/trackerdata.dat";
        File tracker = new File(pathtracker);

        if (trackerDataExists(this)) {

            ArrayList<File> sourceFiles = new ArrayList<>();
            sourceFiles.add(data);
            sourceFiles.add(tracker);

            ArrayList<String> destFiles = new ArrayList<>();
            destFiles.add(folder1);
            destFiles.add(folder2);

            for (int i = 0; i < sourceFiles.size(); i++) {
                for (int p = 0; p < destFiles.size(); p++) {
                    try {
                        copyFiles(sourceFiles.get(i), destFiles.get(p));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "Backup created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Code which copies the files:

```
void copyFiles(File sourceLocation, String targtLocation) throws IOException {

        if (sourceLocation.exists()) {
            FileInputStream fin = null;
            FileOutputStream fout = null;
            Log.i("debug", "source " + sourceLocation);
            Log.i("debug", "des " + targtLocation);
            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
                new File(String.valueOf(targtLocation)).delete();
                fout = new FileOutputStream(targtLocation, false);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
            int len;
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
            while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                bufferedOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            fin.close();
            bufferedOutputStream.close();
            fout.close();

            Log.e("debug", "Copy file successful.");

        } else {
            Log.v("debug", "Copy file failed. Source file missing.");
        }
    }
```

Code to get the download destination:

```
public static String getDownloadDestination(Context mCon) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCon);
        return pref.getString("downloadFolder", MYDESTINATION.getAbsolutePath());
    }

public static final File MYDESTINATION = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "Test");
```

Comment: It is unclear what you consider to be 'internal storage'. Please explain. Your files are now on external storage.

Comment: `Log.v("debug", "Copy file failed. Source file missing.");`. That does nkt say much. Change to `Log.v("debug", "Copy file failed. Source file missing: " + sourceLocation.getAbsolutePath());`. Please tell what is logged.

Comment: Hi greenapps, this is logged.
V/debug: Copy file failed. Source file missing./storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mytest.com.test/files/Documents/Test/Bin/data.dat

Comment: Well that is the same path you mentioned at start.

Comment: `but the files are definitely there`. How do you know? What did you use? Which tool?

Comment: Yes I know but the copy still fails.

Comment: Checked with file explorer.

Comment: Which file explorer? You could be more informative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160542/discussion-between-simon-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. If anyone encounters the same issue, below is the working code.

```
public void backupFiles() {

        if (DataExists(this)) {

            ArrayList<String> sourceFiles = new ArrayList<>();
            sourceFiles.add("codex.dat");
            sourceFiles.add("ids.dat");
            sourceFiles.add("data.dat");

            for (int i = 0; i < sourceFiles.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    copyFiles(sourceFiles.get(i));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "Backup of FAVORITES created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

public void copyFiles(String sourceLocation) throws IOException {

        if (!sourceLocation.isEmpty()) {
            FileInputStream fin = null;
            FileOutputStream fout = null;

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + Utils.getDownloadDestination
                    (this) + "/TestBackup/Bin/";
            File rootPath = new File(path);

            if (!rootPath.exists())
                rootPath.mkdirs();

            File sdcardData = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir
                    ("Documents"), "MyTest");
            String pathdata = sdcardData.getPath() + "/Bin/" + sourceLocation;
            File data = new File(pathdata);

            Log.i("debug", "source " + pathData);
            Log.i("debug", "des " + path + sourceLocation);

            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(data);
                File outFile = new File(path, sourceLocation);
                fout = new FileOutputStream(outFile, true);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
            while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                bufferedOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            fin.close();
            bufferedOutputStream.close();
            fout.close();

            //Comment out to delete originals!
            //data.delete();
            Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            scanIntent.setData(Uri.parse(sourceLocation));
            sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
            Log.e("debug", "Copy file successful.");

        } else {
            Log.v("debug", "Copy file failed. Source file missing." + sourceLocation);
        }
    }
```